# How to use nested module styles with AntD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, module, antd

I have antd component

```
<Tabs
  destroyInactiveTabPane
  defaultActiveKey="1"
  items={items}
  className={styles.tabs}
 />
```

And styles .scss module file

```
.tabs {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 16px;

  .ant-tabs-content {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Tabs styles are correctly applying on root className (tabs) but *.ant-tabs-content* has no applied styles. How to style *.ant-tabs-content*?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I realised:

```
.tabs {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 16px;

  :global {
    .ant-tabs-content {
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```